# How do I use conditional logic inside scala require method?

Tags: scala

My Example :

```
class ComplexNum(val real:Int,val imaginary:Int) {

  require((real==0 && imaginary==0 ),"Real or Imaginary, either any one should have value") 

}
```

what I am trying to achieve is commented as below,

```
object main extends App {
  val complexNumber1= new ComplexNum(1,1) //Should Not throw an error
  val complexNumber2= new ComplexNum(0,1) //Should Not throw an error
  val complexNumber3= new ComplexNum(1,0) //Should Not throw an error
  val complexNumber4= new ComplexNum(0,0) //Should throw an error
}
```

Currently I am getting error for first 3 conditions and no error for 4th condition.

Can someone please help me to understand the require method with above example with correct solution?

Comment: you have written require method as real and imaginary variables should always be 0

Comment: Thanks, I've understood require method in other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple case of logic inversion.

```
require(!(real==0 && imaginary==0),"Real or Imaginary, either any one should have value")
```

... can also be expressed as ...

```
require(real!=0 || imaginary!=0,"Real or Imaginary, either any one should have value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written `require` method as `real` and `imaginary` variables should always be 0. **So if you pass any integer value other than 0 then you would have following error**

> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Real or Imaginary, either any one should have value

If you want `Real or Imaginary, either any one should have value` then you should define `require` method as

```
class ComplexNum(val real:Int,val imaginary:Int) {
  require((Option(real).isDefined && Option(imaginary).isDefined),"Real or Imaginary, either any one should have value")
}
```

Comment: I tried testing the solution provided, it is getting passed for all conditions.

Comment: i didn't know that you wanted to avoid having 0 in both real and imaginary :)

Comment: sorry if I failed to explain the scenario in clear way

Comment: It was my mistake that I didn't understand. jwh has understood and given you the right answer :)